# Integration by parts on dot products of two vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

How can we take the integration by parts of the following,

$$ \int_{\mathcal{V}} (\nabla a) \cdot (\nabla b) \;d\tau$$

Where one can also consider $a$ as a scalar over $\mathcal{V}$. I'm not sure how to approach doing integration by parts for a dot product of two gradient vectors. How does one approach this integral?

Answer (score 2):

The key pieces you need in higher dimensions are the product rule:
$$\nabla \cdot (a\mathbf{v}) = \nabla a \cdot \mathbf{v} + a \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}$$
and Stokes's theorem:
$$\int_{\mathcal{V}} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}\,dV = \int_{\partial \mathcal{V}} \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dA.$$
Note that these reduce to the ordinary product rule, and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, in one dimension.

Together they give you "integration by parts" in higher dimensions:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial \mathcal{V}} a\nabla b\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dA &= \int_{\mathcal{V}} \nabla \cdot a\nabla b\,dV\\
&= \int_{\mathcal{V}} \nabla a \cdot \nabla b\,dV + \int_{\mathcal{V}} a \Delta b\,dV,
\end{align*}
where $\Delta b$ is the Laplacian of $b$. Note that in concrete applications it's often the case that the boundary term on the LHS vanishes to zero; but the rule itself does not require or guarantee this.